# Invalid Conversion from uint8_t* to uint8_t fpermissive c++

Tags: c++, arduino, atmelstudio, uint8t

I realize issue has been asked many times, but after reading many many similar questions I am still unable to understand and solve this issue.  I am a novice coder and am still learning, and for many days i have been unable to solve this issue.

I am using a demo code library from arduino and trying to compile it in c++ Atmel Studio 7 (compiling for a custom board i made based on ATSAMD21).  Here is my relevant code (removed all unrelated parts):

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Kalman.h" // Source: https://github.com/TKJElectronics/KalmanFilter
//Beginning of Auto generated function prototypes by Atmel Studio
uint8_t i2cWrite(uint8_t registerAddress, uint8_t data, bool sendStop);
uint8_t i2cWrite(uint8_t registerAddress, uint8_t data, uint8_t length, bool sendStop);
uint8_t i2cRead(uint8_t registerAddress, uint8_t data, uint8_t nbytes);
//End of Auto generated function prototypes by Atmel Studio

#define RESTRICT_PITCH // Comment out to restrict roll to ±90deg instead - please read: http://www.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3461.pdf

Kalman kalmanX; // Create the Kalman instances
Kalman kalmanY;

/* IMU Data */
double accX, accY, accZ;
double gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ;
int16_t tempRaw;

double gyroXangle, gyroYangle; // Angle calculate using the gyro only
double compAngleX, compAngleY; // Calculated angle using a complementary filter
double kalAngleX, kalAngleY; // Calculated angle using a Kalman filter

uint32_t timer;
uint8_t i2cData[14]; // Buffer for I2C data

// TODO: Make calibration routine

#if defined(ARDUINO_SAMD_ZERO) && defined(SERIAL_PORT_USBVIRTUAL)
  // Required for Serial on Zero based boards
  #define Serial SERIAL_PORT_USBVIRTUAL
#endif

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  //TWBR = ((F_CPU / 400000L) - 16) / 2; // Set I2C frequency to 400kHz

  i2cData[0] = 7; // Set the sample rate to 1000Hz - 8kHz/(7+1) = 1000Hz
  i2cData[1] = 0x00; // Disable FSYNC and set 260 Hz Acc filtering, 256 Hz Gyro filtering, 8 KHz sampling
  i2cData[2] = 0x00; // Set Gyro Full Scale Range to ±250deg/s
  i2cData[3] = 0x00; // Set Accelerometer Full Scale Range to ±2g
  while (i2cWrite(0x19, *i2cData, 4, false)); // Write to all four registers at once
  while (i2cWrite(0x6B, 0x01, true)); // PLL with X axis gyroscope reference and disable sleep mode

  while (i2cRead(0x75, *i2cData, 1));
  if (i2cData[0] != 0x68) { // Read "WHO_AM_I" register
    Serial.print(F("Error reading sensor"));
    while (1);
  }

  //delay(100); // Wait for sensor to stabilize

  /* Set kalman and gyro starting angle */
  while (i2cRead(0x3B, *i2cData, 6));
  accX = (i2cData[0] << 8) | i2cData[1];
  accY = (i2cData[2] << 8) | i2cData[3];
  accZ = (i2cData[4] << 8) | i2cData[5];

  // Source: http://www.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3461.pdf eq. 25 and eq. 26
  // atan2 outputs the value of -π to π (radians) - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2
  // It is then converted from radians to degrees
#ifdef RESTRICT_PITCH // Eq. 25 and 26
  double roll  = atan2(accY, accZ) * RAD_TO_DEG;
  double pitch = atan(-accX / sqrt(accY * accY + accZ * accZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
#else // Eq. 28 and 29
  double roll  = atan(accY / sqrt(accX * accX + accZ * accZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
  double pitch = atan2(-accX, accZ) * RAD_TO_DEG;
#endif

  kalmanX.setAngle(roll); // Set starting angle
  kalmanY.setAngle(pitch);
  gyroXangle = roll;
  gyroYangle = pitch;
  compAngleX = roll;
  compAngleY = pitch;

  timer = micros();
}

void loop() {
  /* Update all the values */
  while (i2cRead(0x3B, *i2cData, 14));
  accX = ((i2cData[0] << 8) | i2cData[1]);
  accY = ((i2cData[2] << 8) | i2cData[3]);
  accZ = ((i2cData[4] << 8) | i2cData[5]);
  tempRaw = (i2cData[6] << 8) | i2cData[7];
  gyroX = (i2cData[8] << 8) | i2cData[9];
  gyroY = (i2cData[10] << 8) | i2cData[11];
  gyroZ = (i2cData[12] << 8) | i2cData[13];

  double dt = (double)(micros() - timer) / 1000000; // Calculate delta time
  timer = micros();

  // Source: http://www.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3461.pdf eq. 25 and eq. 26
  // atan2 outputs the value of -π to π (radians) - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2
  // It is then converted from radians to degrees
#ifdef RESTRICT_PITCH // Eq. 25 and 26
  double roll  = atan2(accY, accZ) * RAD_TO_DEG;
  double pitch = atan(-accX / sqrt(accY * accY + accZ * accZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
#else // Eq. 28 and 29
  double roll  = atan(accY / sqrt(accX * accX + accZ * accZ)) * RAD_TO_DEG;
  double pitch = atan2(-accX, accZ) * RAD_TO_DEG;
#endif

  double gyroXrate = gyroX / 131.0; // Convert to deg/s
  double gyroYrate = gyroY / 131.0; // Convert to deg/s

#ifdef RESTRICT_PITCH
  // This fixes the transition problem when the accelerometer angle jumps between -180 and 180 degrees
  if ((roll < -90 && kalAngleX > 90) || (roll > 90 && kalAngleX < -90)) {
    kalmanX.setAngle(roll);
    compAngleX = roll;
    kalAngleX = roll;
    gyroXangle = roll;
  } else
    kalAngleX = kalmanX.getAngle(roll, gyroXrate, dt); // Calculate the angle using a Kalman filter

  if (abs(kalAngleX) > 90)
    gyroYrate = -gyroYrate; // Invert rate, so it fits the restriced accelerometer reading
  kalAngleY = kalmanY.getAngle(pitch, gyroYrate, dt);
#else
  // This fixes the transition problem when the accelerometer angle jumps between -180 and 180 degrees
  if ((pitch < -90 && kalAngleY > 90) || (pitch > 90 && kalAngleY < -90)) {
    kalmanY.setAngle(pitch);
    compAngleY = pitch;
    kalAngleY = pitch;
    gyroYangle = pitch;
  } else
    kalAngleY = kalmanY.getAngle(pitch, gyroYrate, dt); // Calculate the angle using a Kalman filter

  if (abs(kalAngleY) > 90)
    gyroXrate = -gyroXrate; // Invert rate, so it fits the restriced accelerometer reading
  kalAngleX = kalmanX.getAngle(roll, gyroXrate, dt); // Calculate the angle using a Kalman filter
#endif

  gyroXangle += gyroXrate * dt; // Calculate gyro angle without any filter
  gyroYangle += gyroYrate * dt;
  //gyroXangle += kalmanX.getRate() * dt; // Calculate gyro angle using the unbiased rate
  //gyroYangle += kalmanY.getRate() * dt;

  compAngleX = 0.93 * (compAngleX + gyroXrate * dt) + 0.07 * roll; // Calculate the angle using a Complimentary filter
  compAngleY = 0.93 * (compAngleY + gyroYrate * dt) + 0.07 * pitch;

  // Reset the gyro angle when it has drifted too much
  if (gyroXangle < -180 || gyroXangle > 180)
    gyroXangle = kalAngleX;
  if (gyroYangle < -180 || gyroYangle > 180)
    gyroYangle = kalAngleY;

uint32_t time = millis();

  /* Print Data */
#if 1 // Set to 1 to activate
  Serial.print(accX); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(accY); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(accZ); Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.print(gyroX); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gyroY); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gyroZ); Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.print(time); Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.print("\t");
#endif
#if 0
  Serial.print(roll); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gyroXangle); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(compAngleX); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(kalAngleX); Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.print("\t");

  Serial.print(pitch); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(gyroYangle); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(compAngleY); Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(kalAngleY); Serial.print("\t");
#endif
#if 1 // Set to 1 to print the temperature
  Serial.print("\t");

  double temperature = (double)tempRaw / 340.0 + 36.53;
  Serial.print(temperature); Serial.print("\t");
#endif

  Serial.print("\r\n");
  //delay(2);
}    

const uint8_t IMUAddress = 0x68; // AD0 is logic low on the PCB
const uint16_t I2C_TIMEOUT = 1000; // Used to check for errors in I2C communication

uint8_t i2cWrite(uint8_t registerAddress, uint8_t data, bool sendStop) {
  return i2cWrite(registerAddress, &data, 1, sendStop); // INVALID CONVERSION ERROR HERE
}

uint8_t i2cWrite(uint8_t registerAddress, uint8_t *data, uint8_t length, bool sendStop) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(IMUAddress);
  Wire.write(registerAddress);
  Wire.write(data, length);
  uint8_t rcode = Wire.endTransmission(sendStop); // Returns 0 on success
  if (rcode) {
    Serial.print(F("i2cWrite failed: "));
    Serial.println(rcode);
  }
  return rcode; // See: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireEndTransmission
}

uint8_t i2cRead(uint8_t registerAddress, uint8_t *data, uint8_t nbytes) {
  uint32_t timeOutTimer;
  Wire.beginTransmission(IMUAddress);
  Wire.write(registerAddress);
  uint8_t rcode = Wire.endTransmission(false); // Don't release the bus
  if (rcode) {
    Serial.print(F("i2cRead failed: "));
    Serial.println(rcode);
    return rcode; // See: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireEndTransmission
  }
  Wire.requestFrom(IMUAddress, nbytes, (uint8_t)true); // Send a repeated start and then release the bus after reading
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < nbytes; i++) {
    if (Wire.available())
      data[i] = Wire.read();
    else {
      timeOutTimer = micros();
      while (((micros() - timeOutTimer) < I2C_TIMEOUT) && !Wire.available());
      if (Wire.available())
        data[i] = Wire.read();
      else {
        Serial.println(F("i2cRead timeout"));
        return 5; // This error value is not already taken by endTransmission
      }
    }
  }
  return 0; // Success
}
```

The above code gives error in the i2cWrite function at line 195 Col 54:

invalid conversion from 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' -fpermissive

Note that i modified the above code first and added an *asterisk to i2cWrite/i2cRead array on lines 43, 46, 55, 83.  If i don't add those then the same exact error on ALL those lines as well.  Since the original code didn't have those *references maybe I wasn't supposed to add those pointers...?

I am trying to learn about pointers and references, but struggling.  For the life of me i cannot understand how to solve this error.  I've tried various & and * but for the life of me can't understand and correct this issue.  I just cant seem to understand how/where my code is trying to assign a uint8_t* to uint8_t.

Per other topics, do i need to cast or use volatile or const to any of these variables?  I don't think so but again i'm a beginner.

I'd be very grateful for anyone to point me in the right direction or help me understand a solution.  In Arduino i can compile and run this code, but not in Atmel Studio.  Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: I've updated the code and removed the comments so that the error and line numbers match up with my post.  Apologies for confusion on the line #s.

Comment: One is a pointer and the other is not. They are not compatible types and implicit conversions cannot be applied.

Comment: Line 195 of your code is right in the middle of a multi-line comment. Could you highlight which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: Guessing where to put stars is not a good way to program. Even if you make error messages go away, it's likely the code is still wrong

Comment: " I just cant seem to understand how/where my code is trying to assign a uint8_t* to uint8_t."  - on line 195, col 54

Comment: I edited the code and added a comment at the line where the error happens.  In the i2cWrite function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the function before calling it.

In the definition of `i2cWrite`, it cannot see the declaration of the overload that receives a pointer as argument. Because of that, the compiler is assuming you are calling the function recursively, in which has a argument with wrong type.

Comment: Thanks but haven't i declared the i2cWrite and i2cRead functions at the beginning on lines 5, 6, 7?  Thx for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem:

```
uint8_t i2cWrite(uint8_t registerAddress, uint8_t data, bool sendStop) {
  return i2cWrite(registerAddress, &data, 1, sendStop); // Returns 0 on success
}
```

As shown by the first line, `i2cWrite` takes 3 arguments: `uint8_t`, `uint8_t`, and `bool`. But then you call it with 4 arguments: `uint8_t`, `uint8_t *`, `int`, `bool`.

Then after that you declare another function called `i2cWrite` that takes 4 arguments. This is not allowed .

It's hard to say but I'm guessing that you wanted these functions to have different names, the 3-argument one and the 4-argument one.

Comment: I slipt these functions out but the error remains.  the i2cWrite with 3 variables became i2cWrite1 for all instances but the error still occurrs.  It actually then occurred on Line 44 Col 35 and Line 195 53.  invalid conversion from uint8_t* to uint8_t.

Comment: I'm an idiot, and you are right.  You got me thinking about the declarations and sure enough, i forgot the derefernce * in my function declarations.  Added that and the code compiles without error.  Much appreciated my friend!  I'll select as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both answers.  The solution was simply my function prototypes at the very beginning were slightly different.  The 2nd i2cWrite declaration was missing the derefernce *asterisk.  That fixed it right up.